# How to wrap text in Silverlight DataGridTextColumn

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to create a simple DataGrid in Silverlight 4 Beta but cannot seem to figure out how to get my `Note` column to wordwrap.

The table represents notes made on an order, so they will be of variable length. i want the 'Note' cell to expand vertically to fit the contents.

I've found numerous similar questions but no answer. Is there something new in Silverlight 4 that will address this?

```
    <data:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" IsReadOnly="True">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding User}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding Note}"  />
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a text column.  Have a TextBlock in there with it's TextWrapping set to true:

```
   <data:DataGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" >
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>

            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding User}" />

            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Note" Width="100">
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Note}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn> 

        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: This will cause scrolling issues if you don't have a RowHeight set on your DataGrid.

Comment: You will not have any scrolling issues if you set your DataGrid height to auto, and wrap the data grid in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: i tried your solution but it results in exception, i am working with silverlight 4

Answer (score 20):

I use ElementStyle to set the wrap text,and it works all right. Happy coding!

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumnStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>

<data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DESC}"   
         Header="Short Description" 
         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}"  
         ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnStyle}"  >
</data:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: This will cause scrolling issues if you don't have a RowHeight set on your DataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

Either of the other solutions work - but they both cause a scrolling problem.

If you have a DataGrid that does not have RowHeight set, then the row height will be determined by the size of these TextBlocks. Well, the DataGrid uses virtualization and doesn't draw the TextBlocks until they are displayed. So it simply does not know how big the scrollbar should be. Scrolling with the middle mouse button then causes all sorts of unfortunate behavior.

I'm using paging on my datagrid so I'm disabling virtualization by setting the DataGrid's Style to this:

```
xmlns:dataprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    xmlns:SystemWindowsControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyleNoVirtualization" TargetType="SystemWindowsControls:DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="#AAEAEFF4" />
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="DragIndicatorStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7FFFFFFF" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <!-- TODO: Change the TargetType to Control when the fix Jolt bugs 18719 is verified -->
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unsorted" />
                                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).ScaleY" Duration="0" To="-.9"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#66808080" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" >
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>

                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                                            <Path Grid.Column="1" Name="SortIcon" Fill="#7FFFFFFF" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8" Margin="4,0,0,0" Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z ">
                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9" />
                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="DropLocationIndicatorStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3F4346"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Vertical" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="SystemWindowsControls:DataGrid">
                        <Grid>
                            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </vsm:VisualState>
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                                <Grid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Grid.Resources>
                                        <!--Start: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->
                                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLeftHeaderTemplate" TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                            <Grid Name="Root">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                    <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFDBDCDC" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                        <!--End: TopLeftHeaderTemplate-->

                                        <!--Start: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopRightHeaderTemplate" TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                            <Grid Name="RootElement">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                    <Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
                                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                        <!--End: TopRightHeaderTemplate-->
                                    </Grid.Resources>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopLeftCornerHeader" Template="{StaticResource TopLeftHeaderTemplate}" Width="22" />
                                    <dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader Name="TopRightCornerHeader" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource TopRightHeaderTemplate}" />
                                    <Rectangle Name="ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="1" Height="1" Fill="#FFC9CACA"/>

                                    <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <dataprimitives:DataGridRowsPresenter Name="RowsPresenter"  />
                                    </ScrollViewer>

                                    <Rectangle Name="BottomRightCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                                    <Rectangle Name="BottomLeftCorner" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle Name="FrozenColumnScrollBarSpacer" />
                                    </Grid>

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="2" Background="#8CFFFFFF" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve scrolling issue you can just strongly set the Height property of TextBlock, for example:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumnStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
</Style>
```